# Locker service - copy to clipboard

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, flash

I need a functionality to copy table data to clipboard. With locker enabled I don't have access to  :

```
document.queryCommandSupported('copy')
document.execCommand('copy');
```

How else can I deliver this functionality. Will Flash work with lightning. I suppose not.

Comment: These functions are now exposed with LockerService enabled. Let me know if you see any issues using the APIs.

Answer (score 4):

I have also faced the same issue. If you use Salesforce CLI to scan your code. It will say that document.execCommand('copy'); is not a secure document function.

Only possible solution I can think of is to use a [prompt](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/notifications/#flavor-prompt)(window.prompt is not supported) with a input box which will show a input selected text and focused. There will be a message over input text 'Please press Ctrl+C to Copy' and on press 'Ctrl+C' prompt will close.

We have already implemented a prompt for our package but I am not sure how good will be the UX of this solution.

Please let me know your thoughts.

> PS: ui:copy is not supported on salesforce. For supported APIs please
>   go to  https://your-org-domain.lightning.force.com/auradocs

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do

```
var doc = document;
doc.queryCommandSupported('copy');
doc.execCommand('copy');
```

It doesn't gives me Lightning CLI errors and it executes fine.
Will this work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The aura framework has a ui:copy event where you can handle when the user has copied content to the clipboard.

See here: http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?descriptor=ui:copy&defType=event

Comment: thanks I didn't see it however my use case is a bit different. I need to programatically execute copy to clipboard on a button click. Ultimately I want also to save the content as csv file as well. One step at a time...

Comment: @user682217 if you want to save data pragmatically then send it to server side action and generate CSV over there.

Comment: I think it is not supported any more, I could not find ui:copy

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by using hidden textarea element.

**modalBody** is the text that will be copied.

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
    <p>{!v.modalBody}</p>

    <TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; opacity: 0;">
        {!v.modalBody}
    </TEXTAREA>
</div>
<footer class="slds-modal__footer">
    <lightning:button aura:id="copy" variant="neutral" label="Close" iconName="action:close" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.close }" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Copy" iconName="utility:copy_to_clipboard" iconPosition="left" onclick="{! c.copy }" />
</footer>
```

On the controller:

```
copy : function(component, event, helper) {
    var holdtxt = document.getElementById("holdtext");
    holdtxt.select();
    document.queryCommandSupported('copy');
    document.execCommand('copy');

    var source = event.getSource();
    source.set('v.label','COPIED!');

    setTimeout(function(){
        component.set("v.showModal", false);
    }, 1500);
}
```